# HttpClient response messege "The operation was canceled.". The json result in postman is [ ]? How to get all data from API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, httpresponse, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using https://www.timeanddate.com/ this API for holiday details.

When I debugge The HttpClient response messege is **"The operation was canceled."**
**'($exception).CancellationToken.WaitHandle' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'**

and response in POSTMAN is **[ ]**  (response type : 200k).

controller

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string country, int year)
        {
            List<Holidays> holidays = new List<Holidays>();
            holidays = await _holidayService.GetHolidays(country, year);

            return Ok(holidays);
        }
```

service

```
   public HolidayService(HttpClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
            _client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
        }

        public async Task<List<Holidays>> GetHolidays(string country, int year)
        {
            string url = string.Format($"/holidays?accesskey=ACCESSKEY&secretkey=SECRET&version=3&country=ro&year=2021&lang=en");
            var result = new List<Holidays>();

            try
            {
                using var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
            }
            // Filter by InnerException.
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex) when (ex.InnerException is TimeoutException)
            {
                // Handle timeout.
                Console.WriteLine("Timed out: " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                // Handle cancellation.
                Console.WriteLine("Canceled: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return result;


        }
```

startup

```
  HttpClientsConfig.InjectServices(services, Configuration);
            services.AddHttpClient<IHolidayService, HolidayService>(c =>
            {
                c.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Holiday:Url"));
                c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            });
```

AppSetting.development.json

```json
"Holiday": {
  "AccessKey": "MY_ACCESS_KEY",
  "SecretKey": "MY_SECRET_KEY",
  "Url": "https://api.xmltime.com"
}
```

HOW CAN I GET ALL RESPONSE WHICH IS LIKE THIS [https://api.xmltime.com/holidays?accesskey={MY_ACCESS_KEY}&secretkey={MY_SECRET_KEY}&version=3&country=ro&year=2021&lang=en](https://api.xmltime.com/holidays?accesskey=%7BMY_ACCESS_KEY%7D&secretkey=%7BMY_SECRET_KEY%7D&version=3&country=ro&year=2021&lang=en)

I was trying to get API response more than 4 days.  Please help me..
Advanced Thanks.

Comment: Try mapping the result value like below private static async Task<Holiday> GetHoliday(string country, int year) { using var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead); httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // throws if not 200-299 try { return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<Holiday>(); } catch // Could be ArgumentNullException or UnsupportedMediaTypeException { Console.WriteLine("HTTP Response was invalid or could not be deserialised."); } return null; }

Comment: @Gops I got `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.` this response. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to deserialize the response like below

```
  public async Task<List<Holidays>> GetHolidays(string country, int year)
    {
        string url = string.Format($"/holidays?accesskey=ACCESSKEY&secretkey=ACCESSKEY&version=3&country=ro&year=2021&lang=en");
        var result = new List<Holidays>();

        try
        {
           _client.Timeout= Timespan. FromMinutes(30);
            using var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
            string jsonString= await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var root=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
            return root.holidays;
        }
        // Filter by InnerException.
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex) when (ex.InnerException is TimeoutException)
        {
            // Handle timeout.
            Console.WriteLine("Timed out: " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            // Handle cancellation.
            Console.WriteLine("Canceled: " + ex.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Alternatively you can use the nuget package

```
dotnet add package TimeAndDate.Services

var country = "no";
var service = new HolidaysService('accessKey', 'secretKey');
var result = service.GetHolidaysForCountry(country, 2020);
```

Comment: what is ROOT?  anyhow after this line `using var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);` it goes to exception. I get same result.

Comment: Root is a class that contains the holiday class, just to make it easy to deserialised data. However I think you are getting a time out getting the data. I updated my answer to increase timeout to 30mins, can you try adding that to see you are getting the data.